# Tinymce 4 in orchard cms cannot upload images

Tags: image, orchardcms, tinymce-4

I use Orchard cms.I had installed tinymce 4 module.I upload a photo,my photo is shown in editor but when I refresh the website the path of image is change and I cant see the photo.
the image url changed to 
../../../../../Media/Default/pic/7-23-2016-10-10-03-PM-300x200.jpg

Comment: Orchard has tiny mce out of the box, why did u need to install a module for it?

Comment: @HosseinPanahloo because the defualt tiny mce has less future.for example I want to change the font size or change font color in editor

Comment: I see, Maybe instead of uploading images straight to tiny mce, use images from media to insert in editor, it work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the default TinyMCE module has all tiny plugins, by default it will load some of them,then the best way is to extend it and add more plugins as you want.

To do this, you have to replace the default `orchard-tinymce.js` file in your module, and register it in your `ResourceManifest`, to tell Orchard to load your script instead of the default one:

**ResourceManifest.cs:**

```cs
public class ResourceManifest : IResourceManifestProvider {
    public void BuildManifests(ResourceManifestBuilder builder) {
        var manifest = builder.Add();
        manifest.DefineScript("OrchardTinyMce").SetUrl("orchard-tinymce.js").SetDependencies("TinyMce");
    }
}
```

**orchard-tinymce.js:** (You can copy it from \Modules\TinyMce\Scripts\orchard-tinymce.js)

```js
var mediaPlugins = "";

if (mediaPickerEnabled) {
    mediaPlugins += " mediapicker";
}

if (mediaLibraryEnabled) {
    mediaPlugins += " medialibrary";
}

tinyMCE.init({
    selector: "textarea.tinymce",
    theme: "modern",
    schema: "html5",
    // Here you can add your plugins
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern",
        "fullscreen autoresize" + mediaPlugins
    ],
    // Here you can customize your toolbar
    toolbar: "undo redo cut copy paste | bold italic | bullist numlist outdent indent formatselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify ltr rtl | " + mediaPlugins + " link unlink charmap | code fullscreen",
    convert_urls: false,
    valid_elements: "*[*]",
    // Shouldn't be needed due to the valid_elements setting, but TinyMCE would strip script.src without it.
    extended_valid_elements: "script[type|defer|src|language]",
    //menubar: false,
    //statusbar: false,
    skin: "orchardlightgray",
    language: language,
    auto_focus: autofocus,
    directionality: directionality,
    setup: function (editor) {
        $(document).bind("localization.ui.directionalitychanged", function(event, directionality) {
            editor.getBody().dir = directionality;
        });
    }
});
```

You can customize TinyMCE initialize configuration as you need.

Comment: You may also need to call `.SetVersion()` on the resource definition in order to bump the priority of your custom implementation. Otherwise a simple `Script.Require()` may load the original script instead.

Comment: @Xceno you are right but not for this case, since the original resource registration don't has a version.

Comment: Ah my bad, didn't look it up before writing this comment